# How should I deal with Views URL parameter "page" in Google web master tool?

Tags: views, paging

I have node view which has pager with URL parameter "page". I want Google bot crawls all the pages ( `page=1` `page=2` `page=3...` ) but regard all of them as just one and only the first page (without parameter "page") should appear on the search result.

On the webmaster setting page I have set URL parameter for "page" as below but now I'm getting duplicated title and description.

> How does this parameter affect page content: `Paginates`
>   Which URLs with this parameter should Googlebot crawl: `Every URL`

What's the best way to configure URL parameter for Views "page" on Google Webmaster Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "best way" I think. It depends on your site niche. 
I have a blog and it has page=X like URL params. I have set it as "paginates" and "Crawl all pages" same as your setup. 
It now crawls and shows all pages.
That duplicate title problem is still there at my site. I don't mind it because I didn't receive any dupe problem from Google.

If you really want to change it, you can do it in template.php level.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
 if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0){
   $vars['head_title'] = str_replace('|', '('.t('Page @pager', array('@pager' => $_GET['page'] + 1)).') |', $vars['head_title'], 1);
 }
}
```

This will rewrite your HTML title tag's content to "My Blog Posts (Page 2) | MyAwesomeBlog" on Pages where a pager is set. We add 1 to the pager value because when you are on page=1, it's actually the second page for human users.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module for Drupal 6 or [Meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag/) for Drupal 7.
These modules will allow you configure the NOINDEX and NOFOLLOW parameters for listing pages in order to get only 1st page in SERP.

Comment: The question is how to change the settings on Google Webmaster Tools, not on the Drupal site.

Comment: Then you have asked question in wrong forum.

Comment: I didn't ask the question. Still, this is not the answer for the asked question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't see a setting in Google Webmaster Tools to do this however, you could actually do this in your robots.txt file that ships with drupal by adding at the bottom:

Disallow: /*?page=

Disallow: /*?page=*&*

Disallow: /*?page=0*